# How many Lailathul Qadr nights are there for a year in Islam?

Tags: quran, laylat-al-qadr

I saw a post that the night of Qadr is one of the odd nights of last 10 days of fasting and a post in Quran states that the angels were come to earth. So the night of Qadr would one day per year.

But, the fasting count differ from different countries, for ex, between gulf country and India time differs by only 2 to 3 hours, but the fasting count differs by one.

Then what about the night of Qadr between these countries?

Does the angels come two times for these countries?

Totally how many nights of Qadr are for the whole world according to Islam?

Hope, I'm not insulting Muslims, I asked this to my Muslim friend, he doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various views regarding لیلة القدر. Some believe it is more than one night but I think the belief that it is one night is more prominent. There is no indication in Quran that there are more than one nights. There are several hadith that say or imply that there is one in each year and it is also implied from verses in sura al-Qadr in Quran that it takes place regularly (e.g. from the present tense verb used in verse 97:4: "The Angels and the Spirit *come* down to earth ...", compared to the verb in verse 97:1 which is past tense: "We did send it down in the night of Qadr").

We know from Quran that it is in Ramadan as Quran was sent in Ramadan according to verse 2:185 and in لیلة القدر according to verse 97:1 (though this verse is not very explicit). The exact night of Ramadan is not specified in Quran, famous guesses based on hadith are that it is 23th night or it is 27th night.

The issue that different places on earth might have different nights is not explored in Quran or other early Islamic sources as far as I know. This issue is rather modern. It is like asking what is the day that Ramadan starts or what is the time of the morning prayer in various locations on earth (or even in space). There is not a consensus among Islamic scholars on how to deal with these kind of issues which have more practical importance compared to your question.

Sometimes God does not want the answer to some question to be known (verse 18:22) or humans are simply incapable of knowing the answer (verse 17:85) or sometimes knowing the answer is not useful or beneficial (verse 5:100-101, or verse about the cow in second sura). A question that I normally ask in response to this kind of questions is why one would want to know the answer? In this case, why would you want to know the exact night? Is it out of idle curiosity or for something practically important? For a good Muslim I guess the interest in knowing the exact date might be to know which night to perform prayers and other good deeds more than other nights. So *maybe* God wanted to conceal the exact date of the night so people will not forget other nights of Ramadan by focusing too much on just that night (as it seems to me if God wanted the exact date to be known and emphasized that would be the case). And God knows best.

Answer (score 0):

It is on odd nights . eg If Saudi has it on 23 night then the laylatul Qadr starts there on their night and this night will pass on from countries to countries and will end in Asia approximately.